# drop partitioned table with columnar storage

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created a partitioned table with `pg_partman` extension, and then use columnar storage on all children on postgresql hyperscale (citus extension).

```
CREATE TABLE test (dt timestamp, a integer) PARTITION BY (dt);
SELECT partman.create_parent('public.test', 'dt', 'native', 'daily');
SELECT
    alter_table_set_access_method(nmsp_child.nspname || '.' || child.relname, 'columnar')
FROM pg_inherits
    JOIN pg_class parent            ON pg_inherits.inhparent = parent.oid
    JOIN pg_class child             ON pg_inherits.inhrelid   = child.oid
    JOIN pg_namespace nmsp_parent   ON nmsp_parent.oid  = parent.relnamespace
    JOIN pg_namespace nmsp_child    ON nmsp_child.oid   = child.relnamespace
WHERE parent.relname='test' and nmsp_parent.nspname='public';
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('2021-01-01'::timestamp, 1);
```

I have followed the [documentation](https://github.com/pgpartman/pg_partman/blob/master/doc/pg_partman_howto_native.md#undoing-native-partitioning) to drop the table

```
CREATE TABLE test_single (LIKE test);
CALL partman.undo_partition_proc('public.test', p_interval := '1 day'::text, p_batch := 1000, p_target_table := 'public.test_single', p_keep_table := false);
DROP TABLE test_single;
```

However, while this works for row-oriented tables, the `undo_partition_proc` line raises an error because of the columnar mode

```
SQL Error [P0001]: ERROR: UPDATE and CTID scans not supported for ColumnarScan
CONTEXT: SQL statement "WITH move_data AS (
                                    DELETE FROM public.test_default WHERE dt <= '2021-01-02 00:00:00+01' RETURNING "dt","a" )
                                  INSERT INTO public.test_single ("dt","a") SELECT "dt","a" FROM move_data"
PL/pgSQL function partman.undo_partition(text,integer,text,boolean,numeric,text,text[]) line 359 at EXECUTE
SQL statement "SELECT partitions_undone, rows_undone FROM partman.undo_partition ('public.test', p_keep_table := 'f', p_lock_wait := '0', p_batch_interval := '1 day', p_target_table := 'public.test_single')"
```

What is the correct way to drop a partitioned table when the children are in columnar storage?

Note:
pg version 13
citus version 10.0
single node

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to switch back to heap mode before calling `undo_partition_proc` with

```
SELECT
    alter_table_set_access_method(nmsp_child.nspname || '.' || child.relname, 'heap')
FROM pg_inherits
    JOIN pg_class parent            ON pg_inherits.inhparent = parent.oid
    JOIN pg_class child             ON pg_inherits.inhrelid   = child.oid
    JOIN pg_namespace nmsp_parent   ON nmsp_parent.oid  = parent.relnamespace
    JOIN pg_namespace nmsp_child    ON nmsp_child.oid   = child.relnamespace
WHERE parent.relname='test' and nmsp_parent.nspname='public';
```